# Removing duplicates across multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a **CSV** file with multiple columns each containing email addresses. I want to remove any duplicates within the entire file.

- Anyone have an answer for this using R?

Comment: You best of finding the information elsewhere, and when it doesn't work or you can't get it working come back with the errors. You will struggle to get people able to help you with the above information

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert you dataframe to a vector and extract all unique values:

`email_address_vector <- unique( as.vector(t(df)) )`

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(email1 = c('foo@foo.com', 'foo@bar.com'),
                     email2 = c('foo@foo.com', 'foo@baz.com'),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

all_unique_emails <- unique(c(df$email1, df$email2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of depends on what you want in the end, do you want the exact same csv file with NAs in place of the duplicated emails? Or do you just want a list/vector of unique emails?

Take a look at the functions unique() and duplicated(), they should be able to at least tell whether the email already exists.